# MySQL "Packet for query too large" with query length exactly matching `max_allowed_packet`

Tags: mysql

I'm writing a tool that imports tables from a source to a dest, and it generates queries to do the importing. Currently, my tool is aware of what the dest `max_allowed_packet` is set to and only writes insert queries with enough rows as to not go over this limit.

Problem is, I happen to have stumbled upon a query that is `exactly` 1048576 (1MB), or my set max packet size. I would of course assume that a packet contains more than just the query, so this makes sense to me, but how do I find out what the actual max length of a single query with no parameters should be, given a max packet size?

I saw this post already that says to essentially divide the packet size by 11 to get my query length (actually saying the biggest param len * 11 should be the max packet size), but that sounds silly.

Comment: I believe it's supposed to be Packet size / 8, but it's not fixed because it entirely depends on the query metadata used before the actual query such as if it's to run parameter binding or not. with that being said i tend to go for leave a 10 to 20% overhead safety net, but don't forget each character could be a 2, 4, 8 or 16 bit in length depending on the encoding

Comment: @Barkermn01 exactly, I have it at 90% and it works now, but that seems like a lot of space to waste, especially if you set packet size to something large like 1GB

Comment: the TCP max packet size is 65535 Bytes (63.990 KB), and even then you don't ever want it big because the bigger it is the more that has to be re-transmitted should the packet fail, also the bigger the packet the bigger and longer the validation at TCP is

Comment: That sounds fair actually, I'll just stick with my percent buffer then @Barkermn01

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So this is so hard to answer as there is no fixed length, this is just some of the factors that play into TCP packet sizes

So to understand it there is the TCP layer before the MySQL Server, https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transmission_Control_Protocol#TCP_segment_structure

So from that, we can see the TCP header data can be of a varied size due to the options allowed, but critical to TCP there is 140 Bit's to start with, then our MySQL Data starts after the TCP options block so this is before there is any information for MySQL Server to process.

The MySQL server then has to have information about the Encoding, it's options such as is this query parameterized and such and then the query. a character in your string could be one of the common ones 2 bit's ASCII, 8-Bit UTF-8, 16-Bit UTF-16 and possibly I'm not sure if MySQL server supports) 32Bit UTF-32 (note this is the format the string sent to the DB server it is not the format saved by the DB Server)

This is why it's a variable-length and as such, there is no defined Query Size and an example would be the size of the query your write will more than likely be saved into the query header data for MySQL server to know where to stop reading. and that will push the data offsets forward for where the data starts. (E.G the bigger the query the bigger the header for MySQL is).

Another factor to note that the bigger the packet the longer the checksum takes to calculate, and should the checksum validation fail the whole packet has to be re-transmitted so getting these correct is a pain for most Server Software the balance between speed should everything go correctly, vs speed should the packet fail and have to be re-transmitted.